# convert 401k after tax contribution to roth 401k

Tags: 401k, roth-401k

My company recently introduced a Roth 401K option to the traditional 401k retirement account.  I have some existing after-tax contributions (~ $80,000 or so).  If I convert this to a Roth 401K, my understanding is that I have to declare the gains as ordinary income on the amount converted.  Is this true, and if so, how do I calculate how much this would be?

Comment: Can't you sign into the account and see the numbers? The deposits vs the growth?